# How to globally map Java types to UserTypes and database types?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

Given this class:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "mypackage.MyJavaTypeAsMyDatabaseTypeUserType")
    @javax.persistence.Column(columnDefinition = "my_database_type")
    public MyJavaType foo;
}
```

How can I avoid explicitly annotating every field of type `MyJavaType` as I have annotated `MyEntity.foo`?
In other words, how can I globally define that all `MyJavaType` fields in all persisted types are persisted
using `MyJavaTypeAsMyDatabaseTypeUserType` and `my_database_type`?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the open source tool [AutoAnnotator](https://github.com/marco-eckstein/autoannotator) for this purpose. It adds/alters annotations by manipulating bytecode. You can use the Maven plugin or the CLI for other build systems.

You can accomplish the task from my question (and more) by using this configuration:

```java
import com.google.common.collect.*
import com.marcoeckstein.autoannotator.api.*;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

public class Config {

    @AutoAnnotatorConfigSource
    public static AutoAnnotatorConfig get() {
        return new AutoAnnotatorConfig(
            new ClassFilter("mypackage.domain.model"),
            new ClassOptions(
                ImmutableMap.of(
                    MyJavaType.class.getName(),
                    ImmutableSet.of(
                        new AnnotationInfo(
                            Type.class,
                            ImmutableMap.of("type", "mypackage.MyJavaTypeAsMyDatabaseTypeUserType")
                        ),
                        new AnnotationInfo(
                            Column.class,
                            ImmutableMap.of("columnDefinition", "my_database_type")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

The entity class does not need explicit annotations anymore:

```java
package mypackage.domain.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    public MyJavaType foo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option of using `SessionFactory`, you can use the following boot sequence:

```
    StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry =
        new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();

    MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry);

    MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder = metadataSources.getMetadataBuilder();

    metadataBuilder.applyTypes(
        new TypeContributor() {

          @Override
          public void contribute(
              TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
            typeContributions.contributeType(
                new MyJavaTypeAsMyDatabaseTypeUserType(), new String[] {MyJavaType.class.getName()});
          }
        });

    Metadata metadata = metadataBuilder.build();

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = metadata.buildSessionFactory();
```

Note that this solution only eliminates the usage of `@org.hibernate.annotations.Type`, not `@javax.persistence.Column`.

Comment: I have not verified your answer because I am using Spring Boot, but it led me to this other solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58654380/443836

Answer (score 1):

By defining a global converter

```
@Converter(autoApply=true)
public class MyJavaConverter implements AttributeConverter<MyJavaType,MyJavaTypeAsMyDatabaseTypeUserType> {
public MyJavaTypeAsMyDatabaseTypeUserType convertToDatabaseColumn (MyJavaType attrib) {
return someConversionMethod(attrib);
}
public MyJavaType convertToEntityAttribute (MyJavaTypeAsMyDatabaseTypeUserType dbData) {
return someConversionMethod2(dbData);
}
}
```

Comment: In your code, `MyJavaTypeAsMyDatabaseTypeUserType` (which implements interface `org.hibernate.usertype.UserType`) should be a representation of "my_database_type", shouldn't it? `String` as well. And `URL` should be `MyJavaType`.

Comment: On another note, I will still need `@javax.persistence.Column`.

Comment: Typo corrected... `@Column` is needed if the field's name is different than the database column or you need to specify other attributes.

Comment: I still think, using `MyJavaTypeAsMyDatabaseTypeUserType` here is wrong. From `org.hibernate.usertype.UserType` docs: "A "type" class is **not** the actual property type - it is a class that knows how to serialize instances of another class to and from JDBC." In other words, it is another kind of converter.

Answer (score 1):

Not truly global, but "global enough" for most use cases:

`package-info.java`:

```
@TypeDef(
    defaultForType = MyJavaType.class, 
    typeClass = mypackage.MyJavaTypeAsMyDatabaseTypeUserType.class
)
package mypackage.domain.model; // Contains MyEntity
```

Note that this solution only eliminates the usage of `@org.hibernate.annotations.Type`, not `@javax.persistence.Column`.